# Non-unique foreign key Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

I have two tables, data/model is fake for simplicity purposes:

Table A:

```
Order ID       Delivered
1              Y
2              N
3              Y
```

And

Table B:

```
Order ID       Customer ID    
1              123
1              234
1              455
2              789
```

Order ID is a primary key on Table A, and I want to use it as a Foreign Key on Table B.
Is this acceptable, given that Order ID on Table B is not unique?

Please ignore any normalisation/structural issues, my question is simply whether you can have a non-unique foreign key, I just thought the illustration would help..

Thanks,
Dearg

Comment: `OrderId` should be unique on `A`, not `B`.

Comment: A foreign key is a reference to a UNIQUE key, but the foreign key column on itself is not unique. If that would be unique, you would have a 1:1 relationship, and thus it should be in the same table, not in different tables. There's 3 relationships: 1 to n, m to 1, and m to n. But 1 to 1 is not a relationship (not in Oracle PK/FK context). Therefor, the foreign column should not be unique. When you have few data, it may initially look like it is unique, but further data entry will show that it can not be unique. That is, if your data design is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this acceptable, given that Order ID on Table B is not unique?*

Yes, absolutely. This is the standard way of modeling a 1:many relationship

You should nevertheless find a primary key for TableB. If a customer cannot be assigned to more than one order, then using (order_id, customer_id) as the PK would make sense.

Comment: Great, thank you, as for the primary key on Table B, what about adding a new column "row_id" or something, to act as a primary key, or would it be the same difference using  (order_id, customer_id) as you suggested?

Comment: That depends on whether you want to allow multiple customers for the order or not. If you don't then adding a surrogate key will not buy you much. You still need the unique index (constraint) on (order_id, customer_id) and you wind up with an additional index (the PK index) that doesn't really serve a purpose. If you _do_ allow multiple customers per order, then you will need such a surrogate PK.